# Missing file that was open in another program while renaming it in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, mp3, audio-recording

I'm running Windows 10 (build 1903) and using Cinch Audio Recorder to record streaming audio. Cinch saves the file as both .mp3 and .wav files in default folders when recording stops and titles them *Track1.(filetype)*, *Track2.(filetype)*, and so on. After the track was finished recording, I opened the default save folder so I could move the file, but I wanted to rename it first (which had saved by default as *Track2.wav*). Unfortunately, when I tried to do that, I ran into a dialog box stating the file could not be renamed because it was still open in the audio recorder. It gave me the option to **Cancel** or **Try Again**. **Cancel** did not respond, so I closed Cinch and clicked **Try Again** on the warning dialog box. The file disappeared, leaving an empty folder. I searched for *Track2.wav* in Windows Explorer (widening the parameters to "this PC"), but the search yielded no results. What happened to it?

Answer (score 1):

Cinch , as all the other audio recording softwear, store parts of the recorded audio in a temporary folder and append those to the main file. So when you tried to rename that partial file, it crashed and because you closed the recorder, the partial file is discarded.